# Data not modified during South datamigration

Tags: django, django-south

I am doing a migration that adds a referral code to my custom user model. The field I've added looks like this:

```
refer_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=UUID_10)
```

In my datamigration I've added the following:

```
for u in orm['app.User'].objects.all():
    u.refer_code = UUID_10()
    print u.name + ': ' + u.refer_code
    u.save()
```

However, when I perform the migrations, all of my users have the same code. Different codes for each user are spat out from the `print` command, so it's not a problem with my function.

Weirdly, if I roll the datamigration back (it has no `backwards` method) as well as the previous migration that added the field, and re-apply them, not only does every model have the same data in, it exactly has the same data in as before.

There are other parts of the datamigration (adding objects to the database with `get_or_create`) that are working fine.

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think your function was called rather than new field was created. So try to do two migrations. First add new field with default value. And second fill that field.

Comment: That is what I'm doing.

Comment: Which parts? I've included the relevant code here, everything else is autogenerated by South, so I didn't bother including it.

Comment: So try to check if user instance has attribute 'refer_code' before you  assign value to it.

Comment: I have checked, and it does.

Comment: maybe something weird in model save method?

Comment: There is no custom model save method.